# Extract the left channel from an mp3 file

Tags: sound

I'm trying to control where a sound is going to be heard, in the left

For example, when I import an mp3 file, and I want to hear it only from the left ear, what should I do?

I've never worked with sounds before, so I didn't know where to start. The **Documentation Center** seems very undocumented on this topic.

Comment: *MMA* does not have native mp3 import. You'll need to convert it into a supported format, then import, and you can then manipulate it.

Comment: And can't the mp3 be converted inside MMA? Also, what formats are you talking about?

Comment: You could, I suppose, convert it in *MMA*, but there are far easier ways, including open-source. Search the doc. center for "sound", see the "sound and sonification", "the representation of sound", "audio formats", and the tutorials therein.

Comment: The supported formats for sound import are [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/AudioFormats.html)

Comment: @Arcotick so if you solve the issue with the supported formats, do I understand you correctly, that you want then extract just a channel from that stereo sound? for instance left channel is voice and right channel guitar. you want to extract the voice channel into a mono?

Comment: I want to take an audio file, and manipulate it, just to hear it from one ear. The goal is to make an audio file that has the effect of "virtual barber shop".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first step is to convert the sounds to one of the [supported formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/AudioFormats.html).  I recommend WAV or FLAC.  Then you can [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Import.html) it.  You'll get an expression of the form

```
Sound[SampledSoundList[{leftChannel, rightChannel}, sampleRate]]
```

where `rightChannel` and `leftChannel` are numerical lists of amplitudes.

Generally, if you want to hear the sound from just the left speaker, you need to create an all-zero amplitude list *of the same length* for the right  channel too.

For example, after extracting data from the above expression, you can re-create it as

```
Sound[SampledSoundList[{leftChannel, 0*rightChannel}, sampleRate]]
```

to mute the right channel.

Comment: i thought more of something like: Sound[SampledSoundList[sound[[1, 1, channel]], sample_freq]]. totally overseeing the muting effect by multiplying with zero ;)

Comment: @Stefan Yours is the way to go to extract one channel. But as I understood the question the OP wanted the sound to come only from the left channel and not the right one, hence the  need for an all-zero right channel.